# How to add a GIFTCARD in Google Pay app from Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-pay

I'm trying to add GIFTCARD [From a native Android app](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/implement-the-api/save-passes-to-google-pay#from-native-android-app) to the Google Pay App. For this, I want to use [The native Android SDK](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/implement-the-api/save-passes-to-google-pay#use-native-android-sdk) to connect my app with the Google Pay. But, accordingly to the Google Pay API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/implement-the-api/save-passes-to-google-pay#create-loyalty-class) we need `loyaltyclass` to do this.

I want to develop a app for testing purpose, is there any way to do this without  `loyaltyclass` ?

Or, Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to create a `loyaltyClass` to save a gift card. The documentation uses `loyaltyClass` and `loyaltyObject` as an example but you should be able to replace them with `giftcardClass` and `giftcardObject`: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/pass-verticals/use-cases?vertical=gift-cards

Gift cards are supported by the Android SDK: https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/introduction/about-google-pay-api-for-passes